# R - reading table from a web page

Tags: r

I want to access the table with list of securities from the below mentioned web page.

https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlying_home.htm

I am relatively new to R, with the solutions provided in this forum I tried
readLines() method, tried using the XML library i.e. readHTMLTable() method as well but couldn't access the table from the web page. Further I also tried using GET() using Chrome as a user_agent(since I was getting forbidden error message).
It would be great if someone can look into this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `readHTMLTable()` sounds like a good choice?  Why couldn't you read?  Can you share some code?

Comment: for readHTMLTable() I am getting error - content does not seem to be XML, hence the value is null

Comment: Check the [Terms of Service](https://www.nseindia.com/global/content/termsofuse.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your weblink is not pointing to the right location. If you are using `mozilla firefox`, go to the `Developer` section and under `Network - HTML`, you will see all downloaded html pages. If not, reload the page. One of them is the correct one. I have included it in the following code.

```
library("httr")
URL <- "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlyinglist.htm"
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
GET(url = URL, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"), write_disk(temp))

library("XML")
df <- readHTMLTable(temp)
df <- df[[1]]

> head(df)
  S. No.\n    Underlying\n     Symbol
1        1       INDIA VIX   INDIAVIX
2        2        Nifty 50      NIFTY
3        3        Nifty IT    NIFTYIT
4        4      Nifty Bank  BANKNIFTY
5        5 Nifty Midcap 50 NIFTYMID50
6        6       Nifty PSE   NIFTYPSE
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

```
library(httr)
site <- GET("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlying_home.htm",
         user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"))
content <- content(site, as="text")
parsedHTML = htmlParse(content, asText = TRUE)
```

I inspected the element of the table and I copied the id, and entered it into `xpathSApply`.

```
xpathSApply(parsedHTML,"//*[@id=\"replacetext\"]/table", xmlValue)
```

I suspect that there is an encoding problem with UTF-8, but I am no expert in xpath.